# Error on import data neo4j

Tags: neo4j

```
** LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/coursera/data/test.csv" AS line
MERGE (n:MyNode {Name:line.Source})
MERGE (m:MyNode {Name:line.Target})
MERGE (n) -[:TO {dist:line.distance}]-> (m)**
```

I have the mention error:

> Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/C:/Users/mshendi/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/coursera/data/test.csv

Comment: check that file exists at the specified path, the path in the code block doesn't match your error message by the way

Answer (score 2):

Either you put the file into an `import` directory. If you're on windows using the Neo4j desktop then the `import` directory has to go into the database directory (side by side with `plugins`).

If you use the zip distribution or Neo4j Enterprise it's in `$NEO4J_HOME/import`.

Otherwise you have to disable the security setting in `neo4j.conf` or change it pointing to your data directory.

```
# This setting constrains all `LOAD CSV` import files to be under the `import` directory. Remove or comment it out to
# allow files to be loaded from anywhere in the filesystem; this introduces possible security problems. See the
# `LOAD CSV` section of the manual for details.
dbms.directories.import=import
```

If you ever want to restrict loading from a file-URL you have to disable this:

```
# Determines if Cypher will allow using file URLs when loading data using
# `LOAD CSV`. Setting this value to `false` will cause Neo4j to fail `LOAD CSV`
# clauses that load data from the file system.
#dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true
```

Comment: thanks fro your prompt reply , i`m use Windows 7 , where can i found neo4j.conf  ???

Comment: Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/C:/Users/mshendi/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/ProgramFiles/Neo4jCE3.1.1/import/coursera/data/test.csv

Comment: Check the "Options" Pane of Neo4j Desktop for the config file